# Program becomes unresponsive but is still running

Tags: ruby

```
# Function that calculate sales totals and return output

def sales_total(quantity)
  if quantity >= 100
    price = 8
    quantity * price
  elsif quantity < 100 || quantity >= 50
    price = 9
    quantity * price
  else
    price = 10
    quantity * price
  end
end

# Function that displays output to screen

def display(quantity)
  print "\nFor #{quantity} widgets, the total is: $#{sales_total(quantity)}"
end

# Check user input
def check_value(quantity)
  bool = true
  while bool
    begin
      ans = Integer(quantity)
    rescue ArgumentError
      puts "Error! Invalid Number!"
      print "Enter a whole number: "
      quantity = gets.chomp.to_i
    end
    # also tried the following:
    # if quantity.is_a?(Integer)
    #   bool = false
    # else
    #  next
    # end
  end
end

# Start of program
puts "Welcome to the Widget Store!\n"

print "\nWould you like to purchase a widget? (y/n) "
user_choice = gets.chomp.downcase

while user_choice == 'y'

  print "\nHow many widgets would you like? "
  quantity = gets.chomp

  # Valdiate if user input is a number
  check_value(quantity)

  # Call to sales_total
  sales_total(quantity)

  # Call to output
  display(quantity)

  # Check if user wants to continue
  print "\n\nWould you like to purchase more widgets? (y/n) "
  user_choice = gets.chomp.downcase

end

print "\nThanks for using our store! Come back soon!"
```

### Console view of the program

```
    Welcome to the Widget Store!
    
    Would you like to purchase a widget? (y/n) y
    
    How many widgets would you like? we
    Error! Invalid Number!
    Enter a whole number: 45

**Cursor just continues to blink but will not take keyboard input**

The program had no issues running before adding the check_value function.  Not sure where I am going wrong and have tried several different solutions.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few small logic errors. In your `check_value()` function, you need to return from it at some point otherwise it keeps going in a loop. You can return immediately after the `ans = Integer(quantity)` call because it will raise an error and go to the `rescue` otherwise.

Inside the `rescue` block, do not call `.to_i` because that causes strings to be cast to integer 0, which was not your intent. Instead just use `gets.chomp` so `quantity` remains a string and passes back up the loop to be tested with `Integer()`. This is the reason it became unresponsive - after casting the string to integer 0 with `.to_i`, it passed the `Integer()` test but did not return from `check_value()` or exit the `while` loop by setting `bool = false`. It did not need to prompt for input because the conditions were met.

```
def check_value(quantity)
  bool = true
  while bool
    begin
      ans = Integer(quantity)
      
      # Return the valid int here
      return ans 
    rescue ArgumentError
      puts "Error! Invalid Number!"
      print "Enter a whole number: "

      # Do not cast it with .to_i, leave it as a string
      # to be tested again on the next while loop iteration
      quantity = gets.chomp
    end
  end 
end
```

Then when you call the `check_value()` function, you need to assign its return value back to `quantity` for use in `sales_total()`, otherwise it would pass the original input `quantity` (which might have been invalid)

```
while user_choice == 'y' 

  print "\nHow many widgets would you like? "
  quantity = gets.chomp

  # Valdiate if user input is a number
  # And store the return back to quantity
  quantity = check_value(quantity)                                                                  

  # Call to sales_total
  # using the newly validated quantity var
  sales_total(quantity)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I had returned a value at one point in my attempts but completely forgot about reassigning the value passed to the check_value() back to the quantity variable, which explains a lot, and not sure how I missed it.  Your explanation makes sense looking at it now.